# Make a specific tile from a TileMap functional

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework, tiled

I have the following map created with the Tiled software and I want to make the chest functional. Actually, I want to know when the player and the chest overlap but even searching for hours I can't find a solution.

I am using ARCADE physics. I tried using object layers but nothing works...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One very simple solution is to place an object over the chest in a seperate object layer.
When you are loading the map into your game, check for all objects in that layer and store it somewhere (e.g. in a List)

During your game you can easily check if your player overlaps one of your chests.

Hint:
you can give your chest-objects an id and other parameters to define their behavior.

An implementation looks something like this:

Your objects appear in your .tmx

```
<objectgroup name="Container" offsetx="0" offsety="2">
  <object id="148" name="Chest1" x="72" y="3654">
   <properties>
    <property name="state" value="chest_closed"/>
    <property name="epic_Items" value="false"/>
    ...
   </properties>
  </object>
 </objectgroup>
```

Now just parse them into your game logic

```
List<ItemContainer> lootableContainers = new List<ItemContainer>();
foreach (var o in curMap.ObjectGroups["Container"].Objects)
    lootableContainers.Add(new ItemContainer([o.params]));
```

Comment: You could also place the chest itself as an object instead, using the "Insert Tile" tool. That way you avoid double-maintenance between the tile layer and object layer.